# Display an array from a method using another method?

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

I basically want to display an array from a method with a method on my main method.
The first method is the one with the array and the second one is the one that I want to use to display it but I don't know how.

Sorry if this is painfully obvious, I just can't figure it out

```
static public string[] MakeInsults(string[] sNames, string[] sVerbs, string[] sObjects, out int iNumber)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    Utility.GetValue(out iNumber, "Enter the number of insults to generate: ", 5, 100);
    string[] Insults = new string[iNumber];

    for (int i = 0; i < Insults.Length; i++)
    {
        Insults[i] = sNames[random.Next(0, 4)] + " " + sVerbs[random.Next(0, 4)] + " " + sObjects[random.Next(0, 4)];
    }

    return Insults;
}
static public string DisplayInsults(string[] sInsults)
{
   //Use this to display MakeInsults()
}
```

Comment: Just console write the content in array?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two ways:

- Call `MakeInsults()` From  `DisplayInsults()` : For this you need to do following changes in the DisplayInsults;

> Change return type of `DisplayInsults` to void and then no arguments
>   are needed. the method will be like the following:

```
static public void DisplayInsults()
{
    Console.WriteLine("The elements in the array are:\n");
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n",MakeInsults(sNames,sVerbs,sObjects,iNumber));
}
```

- Call `DisplayInsults()` From  `MakeInsults()`: For this you need to do following changes in the `MakeInsults`;

> Change return type of `MakeInsults` to void and then call the `DisplayInsults` in place of return. the method will be like the following:

```
static public void MakeInsults(string[] sNames, string[] sVerbs, string[] sObjects, out int iNumber)
{
    //Process your statements;
    DisplayInsults(Insults);
}
```

Where the `DisplayInsults` will be defined like the following:

```
static public void DisplayInsults(string[] sInsults)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The elements in the array are:\n");
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n",sInsults);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's console app:

```
public static void DisplayInsults(string[] sInsults)
 {
   for (int i = 0; i < sInsults.Length; i++) {
     System.Console.Out.WriteLine(sInsults[i]);
 }
```